# States for Tight Maassen-Uffink Uncertainty Relation

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, entropy

I was reading this paper titled

["Entropic Uncertainty Relations and their Applications"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04857.pdf). There,at equation (47) we have the Maassen-Uffink uncertainty relation which states that for a pair of mutually unbiased measurements $X$(Hadamard) and $Z$(computational), and a quantum state $\rho_A$, the following holds (H is entropy):

$$
H(Z) + H(X) \ge 1 + H(A). 
$$
Meaning, the sum of uncertainties for the resulting random variable $Z$ and $X$ is at least one plus the von Neumann entropy of the state.

Then after equation (47), they mention that this inequality is tight for states which are diagonal in either the $Z$ or the $X$ basis, which I have checked experimentally. My question is, what is the significance of this statement? I.e., what set of states would produce an equality for that inequality and what states won't? Any elaboration? Can we perform some operation on an arbitrary state to make it diagonal in the computational $Z$ basis?

Comment: Yes, you can always change the basis in which your state is diagonal to the $Z$ basis (or any other basis). Just conjugate with the relevant basis change unitary, i.e. $\rho \mapsto U \rho U^\dagger$ where $U$ is the unitary that maps the eigenvectors of $\rho$ to the computational basis.

Comment: It's also quite easy to see why being diagonal in $Z$ or $X$ implies the inequality is tight. If you're diagonal in $Z$ then $H(A) = H(Z)$ and so you have the relation $H(X) \geq 1$ which is clearly tight as $H(X) \leq 1$ is always satisfied.